# renaming particular files in the subfolders with full directory path

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, find, rename

experts, i have many folders and inside the folder there are many sub-folders and the sub-folders contain many files.However, in all the sub-folders one file name is same that is input.ps.Now i want to rename the same input.ps with full path plus file name

so input.ps in all directories should be renamed to home_wuan_data_filess_input.ps

i tried

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/wuan/data/filess/*.ps
do
mv $file $file_
done
```

But it does not do the same as i expect,i hope experts will help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so `input.`ps in all directories should be renamed to `home_wuan_data_filess_input.ps`

You may use this `find` solution:

```sh
find /home/wuan/data/filess -type f -name 'input*.ps' -exec bash -c '
for f; do fn="${f#/}"; echo mv "$f" "${fn//\//_}"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Please note that `echo` is there for testing purpose only. Once you're satisfied with the output just remove `echo` before `mv`

Comment: i will test and let you know @anubhava

Comment: no it is not working...actually my files are little different like input_c1.ps, input_c4.ps, input_c2.ps etc...but it gives last file only i did -type f -name 'input.ps' to -type f -name 'input_b*.ps'

Comment: Yes I just updated. We just need `-name 'input*.ps'`

Comment: let me check sir

Comment: sir it writes only one file which prints on the first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228265/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sion).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so `file` will end up being

```
/home/wuan/data/filess/input.ps
```

What we need here is the path, and the full, snake-cased name. Let's start by getting the path:

```
for f in /home/wuan/data/filess/*.ps; do
    path="${f%*/}";
```

This will match the substring of `f` up until the last occurrence of `/`, effectively giving us the path.

Next, we want to snake_case all the things, which is even easier:

```
for f in /home/wuan/data/filess/*.ps; do
    path="${f%*/}";
    newname="${f//\//_}"
```

This replaces all instances of `/` with `_`, giving the name you want the new file to have. Now let's put all of this together, and move the file `f` to `path/newname`:

```
for f in /home/wuan/data/filess/*.ps; do
    path="${f%*/}";
    newname="${f//\//_}"
    mv "${f}" "${path}/${newname}"
done
```

That should do the trick

---

Here's one of many sites listing [some of the bash string manipulations](https://unixutils.com/string-manipulation-with-bash/) you can use.

Sorry for the delayed update, the power in my building just cut out :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line;
do 
   fil=${line//\//_};                             # Converts all / characters to _ to form the file name
   fil=${fil:1};                                  # Remove the first -                                 
   dir=${line%/*};                                # Extract the directory
   echo "mv $line $dir/$fil";                     # Echo the move command
   # mv "$line" "$dir/$fil";                      # Remove the comment to perform the actual command
done <<< "$(find /path/to/dir -name "input.ps")"
```